# How to run npm {bin: script.js} with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am planing to make something similar as lodash custom builds. So in general I want to let user write command like:

```
lodash category=collection,function
```

Which create custom module just with category i specified

I read few tutorials how to run scripts with npm bin. Just in case I understand something wrong I write it what i think.

So if I have *package.json* with this part:

```
"main": "bin/index.js",
 "bin": {
   "snippet": "bin/index.js"
 },
```

and I `npm install -g` console should listen for command snippet and when i write it it run the script `index.js` in folder `bin`.

This part looks it works correctly for me. When i have something simple in my index.js i.e. `console.log('It Works')`.

In standard situation you want to let user pass parameters to script. So i found out that all parameters should be in variabile `process.argv`.

> The `process.argv` property returns an array containing the command line
>   arguments passed when the Node.js process was launched. The first
>   element will be process.execPath. The second element will be the path
>   to the JavaScript file being executed. The remaining elements will be
>   any additional command line arguments.

So i simply console.log it and run script.

1. If I run script via command `snippet -f -a`
   Output is : `[ 'node', 'path/to/file' ]`
2. If i run script via `node bin/index.js -f -a`
   Output is: `[ 'node', 'path/to/file', '-f', '-a' ]`

I dont understand that, its same script but different output. However I try it looks like when i call script via bin command it never pass parameters.

Is here someone who have experience with this? And advise me what i am doing wrong?

Or alternativly is there some other way how to make this?

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: It looks ok. Did you tried with other flags, or long ones? maybe you are using reserved names. (i.e. [mocha source script](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/bin/mocha)). Can you show some example code?

Comment: Hey @Dario thank you for your answer. I did try it with random other characters. I just edited mz package.json and add run test to same file. Even this work correctly, so for example if I call npm run test category=thisIsOne,thisIsTwo it show me this arguments, if i replace npm run test with snippet it doesnt work

Comment: Hey @Dario I found a solution :) Not sure if I fix it with most easy way but it works. Thank you for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It take a time however I have a solution now so hope it help someone later.

**Where was a problem:**

I noticed that my windows has default program to run `.js` file set to `NODE.js` and because it's default setting of course all `.js` files are opening without parameter.

So in my case every `.js` file open with NODE no matter what, I try to changed it to open with something like PSPAD or similar but this basicly open editor instead of execute file.

**How did I fix it:**

1. Instead of using executing .js directly with something I make my `./bin/index.js` binary file (basicly removed `.js` suffix)
2. Added `#!/usr/bin/env node` on top of `index` file
3. Goes to `package.json` and changed  all dependency on `./bin/index.js` to `./bin/index`

Woala! it works :)

p.s. As I mentioned at start I believe there is an option to run this with `.js` as well but I wasn't able to find it. So please if anyone will find it let me know. 
Thanks